# Adding z-index to a window

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

How can I add a zindex value to the following string so that the pop-window is always on top?

```
string winopen = "Window.Open('Details - " + name + "', 'test.aspx', 'dest=" + destination.Value + "&id=" + id.Value + "', [250,250], [100,100], true); return false;";
button1["onclick"] = winopen ;
```

Answer (score 1):

have you try to give your window an focus?

```
var mywindow;
function OpenWindowOnTop(url)
{
   mywindow=window.open(url,'name', ... snip ...[250,250], [100,100], true);
   if (window.focus) {
       mywindow.focus()
   }
}
```

Comment: Suppose I have 2-3 opened windows and if I want to again reload the window#2, will this bring window#2 to the top of all windows? Currently, it refreshes #2 but keeps it behind.

Comment: you can search the open window by name and bring it with focus() to the front again

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using the [Dependent Parameter](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0380__Window/windowopen.htm), It will open the Popup as a Child Window.

Answer (score 0):

Add `winopen.focus();` to bring focus to the newly created window.